# LEFT JOIN filters referrers that joined last 30 days not referrals that joined last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables

TABLE USERS

```
USER_ID------USERNAME------------REGISTERTIME  
1-----------------admin----------1432985224    
2-----------------test ----------1433985224
3-----------------test2----------1332985224
```

TABLE REFERRALS

```
REFERRER_ID----------REFERRAL_ID 
1-----------------------------2
1-----------------------------3
```

how to show with mysql this:

```
user admin have 2 referrals in last 30 days
user test  have 0 referrals in last 30 days
user test2 have 0 referrals in last 30 days
```

Tried:

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    COUNT(referrals.user_id) AS referrals
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    referrals ON
    referrals.referral_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.registertime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-15' ) AND registertime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-18' )
GROUP BY
    users.user_id
```

What it shows is

only users that joined last 30 days and have referrals
but i need it to show all users that HAVE NEW referrals in last 30 days

Wrong:(This shows only users that have joined in last 30 days and have referrals)

`new user1 have 12 referrals
new user2 have 3 referrals
new user3 have 2 referrals`

Correct: (this shows all users that have referrals that joined in last 30 days )

`Old user1 have 52 referrals
New user3 have 28 referrals
Old user33 have 10 referrals`

I hope i explained well

Comment: Why select users.username but group by users.user_id? (Not valid ANSI SQL...)

Comment: You want to filter by the date of referral. At which field is that information saved?

Comment: at TABLE USERS at column registertime

Comment: @jarlh I am being slightly pedantic (and not that I actually condone the behaviour), but if `user_id` is the primary key of the `users` table (seems like a reasonable assumption), then grouping by `users.username` is valid ANSI SQL since it is functionally dependent on `user_id`. i.e. `user_id` uniquely identifies a row, so it would be impossible to have ambiguity about which `username` to select within a group distinguished by `user_id`.

Comment: @GarethD, you are absolutely correct here. But I still believe the old rule "a selected column should either be listed in the group by or be argument to an aggregate function" is great, programmers who follow it makes no mistakes!

Comment: I m new and i love to read all this infos thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring in the information about the referrer and use that for filtering

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(*) AS referrals
FROM users u JOIN
     referrals r
     ON r.referral_id = u.user_id JOIN
     users ur
     ON r.referrer_id = ur.user_id AND
        ur.registertime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-15' ) AND
        ur.registertime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-18' )
GROUP BY u.username;
```

I don't think you need a `LEFT JOIN` for this.  None of your examples have 0 counts.  If you need them as well, then just change the joins in the query.

You should also get in the habit of using the same columns in the `GROUP BY` as you use in the `SELECT`.  This is a good habit that can prevent future errors.

Comment: Can you please type "u" and "r" with full words? i cant track it :(

Comment: @IngusGraholskis Even if your preference is to not use table aliases (not sure why it would be, nobody likes to type more than they have to), it is essential to use table aliases here since the `users` table is referred to more than once so you need to remove ambiguity between the two references.

Comment: @GarethD I know!I m not that good yet it will take me hours till i do it correct :D

Comment: Ok i did it faster then i thought :D And that is the result i wanted :) Thanks allot @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    users.username,
    COUNT(referrals.referrer_id) AS referrals
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    referrals ON
    referrals.referrer_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.registertime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-15' ) AND registertime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-18' )
GROUP BY
    users.user_id
```

Comment: Nothing different from his original query

Comment: Ah I see you have realised your mistake. I cannot remove my DV unless you edit the answer.

Comment: i think this gives the same result